# How do I change the language on my Facebook page?

Tags: facebook

My Facebook page went from English to Spanish. How can I change it back to English?

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on desktop off on the right-hand side below a couple ads you should see several languages listed. If I put my facebook in Spanish it looks similar to

```
Español · English (US) · 
Português (Brasil) · Français (France) · 
Deutsch
```

Another option is to [click this link](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=language&section=account) which will bring you directly to your accounts language page, and on the dropdown menu select the language you would like.